# How I match the original line which in involve in add function?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my @a     = <DATA>;
my @grep  = grep { m/^a/g } @a;
my @grep2 = grep { m/^b/g } @a;
my @xx;
my @yy;

foreach (@grep) {
    my $x = (split)[1], $_;
    push( @xx, $x );
}
foreach (@grep2) {
    my $y = (split)[1], $_;
    push( @yy, $y );
}
my @mv;
my $i;
my $j;
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < @xx ; $i++ ) {
    for ( $j = 0 ; $j < @yy ; $j++ ) {
        my $m = $xx[$i] + $yy[$j];
        push( @mv, $m );
    }
}

foreach (@mv) {
    if ( $_ eq "15" ) {
        print "$grep2[$mv]\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
a 15 c
a 13 m
a 10 c 
b 2  k
b 12 m
b 13 m
b 5  v
b 5  m
b 6  h
b 15 m
b 12 v
b 21 m
b 11 q
b 9  m
b 32 w
```

Add the value of 'a' with 'b' resulting 36 values. But i expecting which values are 15 and that original line in the 'b' print. example 13 from 'a 13 m' and 2 from 'b 2 k' those are add the answer is 15 i expect output is 'b 2 k'.. similarly

```
I expect output
 b 2 k
 b 5 v
 b 5 m
```

Comment: Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  This is your third post to SO, so it's past time that you started doing that.  You'll find that experts are more drawn to help if you help yourself by using basic good coding practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($pre, $num, $suffix) = split;
    push @{ $data{$pre} }, [$num, $suffix];
}

for my $aref (@{ $data{a} }) {
    for my $bref (@{ $data{b} }) {
        print "b @$bref\n" if $aref->[0] + $bref->[0] == 15;    
    }   
}
```